# How to use Babel 6 without Regenerator runtime

Tags: javascript, bsd, babeljs

I've been using Babel 6 in my latest project, and have a simple script that is distributed to our users.  However, our legal team won't allow distributing code that includes the Facebook BSD-style license ( read: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8985541 ), which is causing a problem since Babel includes the Facebook `regenerator-runtime`.

I've double-checked, and the `regenerator-runtime` is included in `babel-core`.  Is there any way around including this dependency, or a way to replace it with another?

Comment: What exactly are you distributing? If it's only the script, I wouldn't think you have anything to worry about because you're not distributing the FB code yourself (but IANAL). If it's the ES5 code that is generated by Babel, it might not even contain any `regenerator` code if your code doesn't contain generators.

Comment: I believe that the `regenerator-runtime` does more than just transpiles code, but also includes it's own functions into your code.  Our legal team has decided that the patents license is viral, and as such would extend to anyone using a package that includes it.  However, the question is more about if we can get it out of Babel, and less about the legal reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

There's [`babel-preset-es2015-without-regenerator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015-without-regenerator) that you can use, that will output generator functions as-is.